# How to implement HTTP/2 stream connection in browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http2

Nowadays HTTP/2 is rising as of its performance.

The recent version of Node.js supports HTTP/2 very well.

https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html

But I have no idea how to implement HTTP/2 client in the browser environment.

https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_client_side_example

The above link shows how to use it in Node.js client.

How can I implement the same client in the browser?

Comment: I don't think http2 client is available on browsers.

Comment: the browser will use http/2 if the server supports http/2 - one does not need to "implement a client" .. you just use XHR or fetch for example

Comment: @JaromandaX fetch or XHR can not control push promises sent from server. I think providing a http2 client on browsers still makes sense.

Comment: or you can use websockets in that case @Lewis (what is a push promise?)

Comment: @JaromandaX I mean you can not control files served via http2 request without an http2 client (events for determining state of each server push, response of each server push, etc)

Comment: Many modern browsers support HTTP/2, so there should be some interfaces for it.

Answer (score 19):

You can’t currently do this. In general HTTP/2 should be transparent in its use to web pages and web applications and so there is no need to implement low level HTTP/2 streams and connection details. That’s part of the beauty of the way it was implemented - the browser takes care of all this and the web page and web application has no need to know whether HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 was used.

A possible exception to that is, is HTTP/2 push and there was a proposal to expose HTTP/2 Push programmatically as part of the Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group (WHATWG): https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/51. Though activity on that seems to have dropped off completely. As there are a few complications in implementing a Push notification api. All in all [HTTP/2 push is complicated, especially because of different browser implementations and bugs](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought/), so trying to expose push messages to a web application is going to be complicated. There are also many who feel HTTP/2 push has limited use and there are better technologies for most use cases, such as [resource hints](https://w3c.github.io/resource-hints/) (for requesting HTTP resources) or web sockets (for two way comms). [Chrome are even experimenting with switching it off completely](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=876765).

Other than push, prioritization might be another use case for exposing low level HTTP/2 details to web applications and perhaps [priority hints](https://wicg.github.io/priority-hints/) will provide a mapping for that eventually, without tying it to HTTP/2 (so it can be used under HTTP/1.1, QUIC or whatever comes in the future).

So IMHO, I don’t see a pressing need to allow creating or managing of an HTTP/2 connection from a web application in the same way that there is not a simple way (AFAIK) of creating a TCP or UDP connection from JavaScript. While that remains the case I don’t think we’ll see much effort to create such a implementation. Even the HTTP/2 client you link to is very basic and just makes a HTTP request - which the browser already allows you to do (though I appreciate that node exposes more details should you want to go lower level than this while the browser does not). For the most part, HTTP/2 stream handling and other low-level details of the protocol probably are best handled transparently by the browser itself -  as they are now.

Comment: The need to a bi-di stream like that in HTTP/2 in a browser may arise from wanting to recreate the websocket functionality - currently with HTTP/2 that's not possible - (truly bi-di exchange of binary data).

Comment: WebSockets are now possible with HTTP/2 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8441) though admittedly no browser has implemented them yet (Firefox has it coming in v65 apparently - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1434137 and Chrome seems to have stalled on this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=801564). Websockets are probably the better option anyway rather than using HTTP, which has more overheads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50956757/http-2-or-websockets-for-low-latency-client-to-server-messages

Comment: that's great to know, thanks for the hint - I expect Chrome will catch up with Firefox with regards to websockets over HTTP/2. Good news altogether!

Comment: My use case is a webapp based on wasm in which I want to use gRPC to communicate with a service.

Answer (score 2):

**In the Client side:**

You don't need to do anything in the browser, just use one that already supports the HTTP 2.0 protocol https://caniuse.com/#search=http2

**In the Server side:**

Depends on the server you are using you need to activate some modules and configurate some files, here you can see some links to server configurations:  https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations

**Regarding the *Server Push* functionality:**

The same, It depends on the server but is important to note that you can configure a: 
Manual Push or an Automatic Push (Auto Push)

Examples:

**Manual Push**

```
server {    
    # whenever a client requests demo.html, also push
    # /style.css, /image1.jpg and /image2.jpg
    location = /demo.html {
        http2_push /style.css;
        http2_push /image1.jpg;
        http2_push /image2.jpg;
    }
}
```

**Auto Push**

```
server { 
    # Intercept Link header and initiate requested Pushes
    location = /myapp {
        proxy_pass http://upstream;
        http2_push_preload on;
    }
}

//httpd.conf or .htaccess (cuando se cargue un html)
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
    Header set Link "</css/styles.css>; rel=preload; as=style"
<FilesMatch>
```