# Use gRPC-web to call google text to speech api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grpc

What would be the flow from a react js app using gRPC-web to call the google text to speech API with no backend (is it possible?).
I am looking to do live speech to text translation.

I noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212455/why-do-browsers-not-support-grpc) it says browser does not natively support gRPC is it true now then what is gRPC-web?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are currently focused on the generic gRPC use case where the user controls both server and client. For these types of "cloud APIs" use case we are definitely going to look into supporting next.